# Cache database data in JSON

Tags: php, database, json, caching

I'm using a framework that loads the table structure from the database everytime I open a page. I'm thinking of using JSON files to cache this data, and let PHP parse them when I need it. Is it better than loading data from the database? Are there another ways to do something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`serialize` and `unserialize` would be quicker, if you are using that data only in PHP.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010699/php-object-caching-performance/) from a few days ago.

Comment: Yes, the data will be used only by my Model class.

Comment: so please read the other topic, it contains helpful references